# Google said that i had malware in my site, but after cleanning the code and asking a review a coundnt solve it.

Tags: indexing, malware

Google said that i had malware in my site, then i deleted all the files and upload just a simple index.html with "hello world". Asked to google check it again, they checked but the answer was that i still had malware. The strange thing is that in the webmasterstools page has the icon to my site has a image of the old one and in google search my old pages keep apearing , its like the site has not been updatade to google, but how can they recheck malware without updating it first(indexing again)? Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0):

To make it harder for people to work out how to spam search result placings google use a time lapse on their webmastertools data. Some things (like the image of your home page) can take a month or more to update. Give it some time. As far as your pages still appearing in search results go, I get DNS errors in webmastertools for pages I removed 6 months ago.